# `Enable Edit and Continue` option does not work in ASP.NET Core 6 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to developing with ASP.NET Core 6 applications. When I start debugging the application, a console window is opened and also a browser with a page loaded.

If I stop debugging, the internal web server is closed so after any minimal change, I need to restart debugging for the changes to be refreshed.

How can I do that in an ASP.NET Core 6 application? So that, I can make changes, recompile and then refresh the browser window without needing to start debugging every time. I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Cheers

Comment: Visual Studio has a button called "hot reload", which recompiles the code and applies changes while the application keeps running. Does this solve your Problem?

Comment: Nothing worked,  but I found that I could change to IIS profile, so, I set that profile out of process. That way, I can work with VS as usual without debugging, however, I got another problem. When I do any change in any Razor view and refresh the browser, the change is not updated. I need to recompile the project so that the change is applied. Do you know a solution about this?

Comment: Not sure. You can try running `dotnet watch` from the command line in the solution directory.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) NuGet package to the project.

2.Add the following in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

For more detail, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-for-all-environments).

Is this what you want?